# RecyclerView Change current item background color

Tags: android

I am stuck at one point, i am coding a streaming media player app. I have done so far till playing the audio by click an item from RecyclerView and playing audio in Service. Now i want send broadcast from service with an id that is playing in background, and receive it in RecyclerView adapter and match that id with the id in the list and update the background of that item.

In short the goal is to match the id of music playing in service with id of item in recylerview and change the background of that item.

These is my Background Service code:

```
public class AudioPlayerService extends Service implements
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener {

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
int currentId = 0;
AudioList currentAudio = null;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
String source = null;
public static int uid = 0;
private Intent notifyIntent;
private TelephonyManager mTelephony;
private PhoneStateListener mStateListerner;
private boolean isPausedinCall = false;
private boolean isPrepared = false;
public static final String BROADCAST_BUFFER = "com.hussaindehgamwala.mumineendownloads.AudioPlayerService.broadcastbuffer";
public static final String BROADCAST_UPDATEAUDIO = "com.hussaindehgamwala.mumineendownloads.AudioPlayerService.broadcastAudio";
Intent bufferIntent;
Intent newaudioIntent;


public AudioPlayerService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    bufferIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_BUFFER);
    newaudioIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_UPDATEAUDIO);

    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.reset();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mStateListerner = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        isPausedinCall = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        if (isPausedinCall) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            isPausedinCall = false;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    mTelephony.listen(mStateListerner, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


    return START_STICKY;
}

public void showNotification(AudioList audiolist) {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AudioPlayer.class);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        // This intent is fired when notification is clicked
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AudioPlayer.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification.
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_24dp);
        builder.setContentTitle(audiolist.getTitle());
        builder.setContentText(audiolist.getAlbum());
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setTicker("Playing Audio");
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    if (mStateListerner != null) {
        mTelephony.listen(mStateListerner, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
    if (isPrepared()) {
        notificationManager.cancel(1);
    }
}

public String getTitle() {
    AudioDB adb = new AudioDB(getApplicationContext());
    AudioList m = adb.getSourcefromId(currentId);
    return m.getTitle();
}


public void toggleMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
}

public void prepareAsync(String source) {
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(source);
            sendBufferIntentBroadcast();
            sendNewAudioSelectedBufferIntent();
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            isPrepared = true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
}

public void prepareMedia(String source) {
    AudioDB audioDB = new AudioDB(getApplicationContext());
    int AudioId = audioDB.getAudiobySource(source);
    currentId = AudioId;
    uid = currentId;
    prepareAsync(source);

}

private void sendBufferIntentBroadcast() {
    bufferIntent.putExtra("buffering", "1");
    sendBroadcast(bufferIntent);
}

// Audio Update Title

public void sendNewAudioSelectedBufferIntent() {
    newaudioIntent.putExtra("audioid", "" + currentId + "");
    sendBroadcast(newaudioIntent);
}

private void sendCompleteBufferIntent() {
    bufferIntent.putExtra("buffering", "0");
    sendBroadcast(bufferIntent);
}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    currentId = currentId + 1;
    uid = currentId;
    AudioDB d = new AudioDB(getApplicationContext());
    currentAudio = d.getSourcefromId(currentId);
    playNext();
}

public boolean isPrepared() {
    if (isPrepared) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void playNext() {
    AudioDB a = new AudioDB(getApplicationContext());
    AudioList audio = a.getSourcefromId(currentId);
    prepareAsync(audio.getSource());
}


@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    sendCompleteBufferIntent();
    playMedia();
}


private void playMedia() {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        AudioDB d = new AudioDB(getApplicationContext());
        AudioList audio = d.getSourcefromId(currentId);
        showNotification(audio);
        MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
        AudioPlayer audioact = new AudioPlayer();
        activity.UpdateTitle(audio.getTitle(), audio.getAlbum());
        audioact.UpdateTitle(audio.getTitle(), audio.getAlbum());
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

public void upDateTitle() {
    MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
    AudioPlayer audioact = new AudioPlayer();
    AudioDB d = new AudioDB(getApplicationContext());
    AudioList audio = d.getSourcefromId(currentId);
    activity.UpdateTitle(audio.getTitle(), audio.getAlbum());
    audioact.UpdateTitle(audio.getTitle(), audio.getAlbum());

}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


@Override
public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {

}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public AudioPlayerService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return AudioPlayerService.this;
    }
}
```

}

My Recyclerview Adpater Class :

```
public class AudioAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AudioAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<AudioList> mDataset;
private Context mContext;
private AudioPlayerService audioPlayerService;
private boolean mBound = false;
private ServiceConnection mConnection;
private MainActivityFragment fragment;
public static String title1 = "";
private ArrayList<AudioList> mDataset1;

@Override
public void registerAdapterDataObserver(RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver observer) {
    super.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer);
}

public AudioAdapter() {

}

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView textView;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public ImageView imageView;


    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textid);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.playImage);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.play);
    }

}


public AudioAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<AudioList> myDataset, MainActivityFragment fragment) {
    this.mDataset = myDataset;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.fragment = fragment;
}


// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public AudioAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                  int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.audio_list_item, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    final AudioList item = mDataset.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckNetwork checkNetwork = new CheckNetwork(mContext);
            boolean isConnected = checkNetwork.isConnectingToInternet();
            if (isConnected) {
                fragment.removenotConnected();
                fragment.playAudio(item.getSource());
                MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
                activity.ResetButtonandPlay();
            } else {
                fragment.showNotConntected();
            }
        }
    });

}



// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}


public AudioList removeItem(int position) {
    final AudioList model = mDataset.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return model;
}

public void addItem(int position, AudioList model) {
    mDataset.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final AudioList model = mDataset.remove(fromPosition);
    mDataset.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}

public void setFilter(ArrayList<AudioList> countryModels) {
    mDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    mDataset.addAll(countryModels);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

  public class BroadCastReciver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

Solution needed:

[These is my activity with recycler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shPqq.png)

Suppose currently 3rd item is playing in background service.
it should be highlighted by changing its background or its text color or the play icon to pause icon,

Note: If someone has solution with Service Binder, its acceptable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

for a example the AudioList has boolean variable mIsPlaying. So it's need to change

you can add boolean variable `mIsPlaying` into `AudioList`. So set `AudioList.mIsPlaying true`, and reset it if need. And check mIsPlaying in `onBindViewHolder`, if it's true set one background another way set default background.

Or you can save selected `AudioList` id in you adapter and check is id equals in `onBindViewHolder` and also change background according to condition

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
   // - replace the contents of the view with that element
   final AudioList item = mDataset.get(position);
   if (item.id == selecedId) {
      holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
   } else {
      holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
   }

   holder.textView.setText(item.getTitle());
   holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckNetwork checkNetwork = new CheckNetwork(mContext);
        boolean isConnected = checkNetwork.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (isConnected) {
            fragment.removenotConnected();
            fragment.playAudio(item.getSource());
            MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
            activity.ResetButtonandPlay();
        } else {
            fragment.showNotConntected();
        }
    }
});

}
```

Comment: what sould be the selecedId? and how to get it from background service

Comment: But what to do in OnResume() method

Comment: you can get **id** of playing track somehow (shared preference, from service, broadcast receiver) onResume and set it into adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged.

also you need broadcast receiver that listens track changing from service.

Comment: Helped me for text color.